# PHP Excel import with Spout very slow on some files

Tags: php, excel

I import several different Excel files with [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) into my mysql database.
Until now I had no problems. All was fast and fine.

But today I got an update of an excel file which had nearly 4000 rows in the past and has grown up to nearly 9000 rows now.

Importing this file gets very very slow from up to rows near by row 4500. The last 200 rows will take over 30 seconds to load.

When I reduce the memory for my PHP server, it will crash importing after allocating 150MB, while the other files with over 80000 rows still work fine.

There is nothing special with the excel file. I also tried to export it to CSV and created a new xlsx file from this CSV list. No changes at all.

But if I import this file (and wait over 5 minutes for it) and after this try to import an other file, the import of this files is also slow.

Has anyone an idea what I can do to debug this strange behavior?

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to see how you are manipulating those files. I have a similar situation where to read data from some very big csv files I used [phpleague/csv](http://csv.thephpleague.com/)

Comment: The problem is not about CSV files. It is about XLSX files. And I am only doing the standard open and read like its shown in the Spout documentation.

Comment: Can you post some code? It seems like you are doing something you should not do if your code crashes because of memory issue.

Comment: Another reason can be how you fetch data from MySQL. Are you using limits? (you can look at https://github.com/adrilo/spout-pdo-example for a example on how to use Spout and MySQL together)